# WordPress - move all media library files to new folder (tricky)

Tags: javascript, php, sql, wordpress

So I have 2 sets of data, registered media library images (there are 11k) and then random images in the /upload folder (about 400k). The problem is those extra files outside of WordPress are not supposed to be there.

The solution is to move the media library images (11k) to a new folder, delete the /uploads folder, and then move them back to a fresh /uploads folder.

**BUT**

How do I use the SQL to move the files? Or if this isn't possible, is there another simple solution to the problem?

Maybe I can use wget to download all images, delete uploads folder, and then upload these files? The files are all in just one folder so I wouldn't need to recreate the WordPress folder structure.

Comment: Maybe [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/245349/change-urls-for-static-content) link help you to think about how to solve this

Comment: Do you have ssh access? Do you have ftp or sftp access?

Comment: @Cedric yes I do, as well as WP-CLI. An issues with sftp is it times out opening the folder because it is so large but I believe the support team at the host can help.